# What is the term that describes someone who is not interested in sex?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

He or she is not infertile. They have normal sex hormones but just they don't find *it* interesting.

To clarify,

For instance, compared to a man (who is ***not*** this) who'd stare at a blonde in a swimsuit, this guy will simply turn his face.

Any term (including slang) would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such a person would be **asexual** or **nonsexual**, their condition would be called [**asexuality** or **nonsexuality**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality):

> Asexuality (or nonsexuality) is the lack of sexual attraction to anyone, or low or absent interest in sexual activity.

There is also a [website](http://www.asexuality.org/wiki/index.php?title=Asexuality) about it (it seems google takes its definition from there), but I cannot reach it to check from behind my current firewall. If google does take it from there, this page says:

> An asexual is someone who does not experience sexual attraction. Unlike celibacy, which people choose, asexuality is an intrinsic part of who we are. There is considerable diversity among the asexual community; each asexual person experiences things like relationships, attraction, and arousal somewhat differently.

Comment: +1 for non-sexual. *asexual* took me to my school days and [biology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asexual) was my favorite subject! :)

Comment: do you know any slang for that?

Comment: In a usually pejorative sense, and especially applied to women, the word _frigid_ (sometimes just _cold_) is used. However, that is usually not related to the actual asexuality, and it is often said of a woman who simply is not interested in sex with the person who calls her frigid. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frigid) explains what _frigid_ actually means.

Comment: @MaulikV As you already know, a lot of terms translate differently in English than in Science subjects. This definitely creates a confusion for those students but still doesn't affect the usability of such words.

Comment: @oerkelens went through that. good option.

Comment: @MaulikV: If you're already informed about sexuality, some people use "ace" as slang for "asexual" in the same way "bi" is used for "bisexual", but it's not very common.

Answer (score 2):

The term "frigid" means "uninterested in sex". I just checked dictionary definitions and they don't say this, but it seems to me that I have only heard this term used to describe a woman who is uninterested in sex, not a man.

A man who is incapable of having sex is called "impotent", but I don't think that's quite what you're looking for. That's "can't", not "doesn't want to".

Comment: And I think a guy who's impotent can still have sex, they just can't reproduce.

Comment: @Jim Arent you confusing _impotent_ with _infertile_? Of course, sex is more than penetration, but _impotence_ is usually used to describe the inability to achieve a (full) erection.

Comment: To person who edited my post to say that the term frigid is "sexist": I'd say maybe, but not necessarily. If you think so, make a comment. Please don't put your words in my mouth.

Comment: @Jim It can actually mean either or (unable to perform the deed, or unable to reproduce when the deed is performed) according to the dictionary I read.

Comment: @crazyeyes http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impotent gives definitions taken from 3 dictionaries. All 3 include inability to have sex. 1 of the three gives an alternate meaning of "sterile". So I think "can't do it" is the more common meaning, thought "sterile" is a possible alternative.

Comment: Whether or not it's sexist, "frigid" would usually be considered a derogatory term (these days, at least; I think it started life as a technical term in psychology).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the person's reasons for not being interested in sex, one or more of the following terms might apply:

- Chaste -- Many people choose to only be interested in sex with their spouse(s).
- Pious -- Chastity is a virtue in many religions.  Jesus taught that looking at a woman (other than one's wife) lustfully is a serious sin.
- Celibate -- Some people choose not to be interested in sex.
- Oblivious -- Some people don't notice people (or aspects of people) that others consider sexually attractive.
- Aspie -- People with Asperger's syndrome (or related syndromes) do not react "normally" to many stimuli.
- Polite -- In many cultures, it is not polite to stare at a woman, even if she is "a blonde in a swimsuit".

Comment: +1.  "Asexual" or "nonsexual" are the terms for somebody who isn't interested in sex at *all*, just as a heterosexual isn't interested in sex with the same sex and a homosexual isn't interested in sex with the opposite sex, but the OP didn't actually specify whether the question was about that or just someone who wasn't interested *on that particular occasion*.

Answer (score -1):

Nonlibidoist is someone who totally lacks a sex drive. If that still doesn't fit, I guess nonsexual works.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].